# Pascal's Rule: How to prove?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving ${{n} \choose {r}}={{n-1} \choose {r-1}}+{{n-1} \choose r}$ when $1\leq r\leq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose-r-when-1-leq)

I have a dilemma here, how can we show Pascal's Rule :

> Show that
>   $$
> \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}, 1 \leq r \leq n.
> $$

I tried solving the right side by substituting everything into the combination's formula but everything gets complicated.. thanks

PS: I tried substituting real valued numbers, and it works, but it should be proof by means of mathematical manipulation.

Comment: tnx. kannapan sampth

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find it.

I think the easiest way to prove this identity is with a combinatorial proof. So we count the same thing in 2 ways. Suppose we have $n$ objects and we are choosing $r$ of them. The left side is that straight out.

Suppose we designate one particular element (it doesn't matter which one, but call it X). Then when choosing $r$ of the $n$ elements, we either have X or we don't. If we do, then we choose $r-1$ of the remaining $n-1$ elements. If we don't, then we choose $r$ of the remaining $n-1$ elements.

Adding these together, we see that the identity follows.

Comment: Oh - he found the duplicate. Vote to close! (But I keep my answer for posterity)