# This exercise states that $C_{n,k} + C_{n,k-1} = C_{n+1,k}$, but I think that is wrong

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a problem from Degroot and Schervish's Probability and Statistics, in 1.8 section, exercise 14.

Prove that, for all positive integers $n$ and $k$ ($n\geq k$),
$C_{n,k} + C_{n,k-1} = C_{n+1,k}$. ($C$ means combination).

I cannot prove this and think that this is wrong.

Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule

Comment: It is correct. There are many proofs, both computational and conceptual (combinatorial).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving ${{n} \choose {r}}={{n-1} \choose {r-1}}+{{n-1} \choose r}$ when $1\leq r\leq n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose-r-when-1-leq)

Comment: @user89855 What makes you think the statement is wrong?

Comment: I thought that n-(k-1) < n-k.  Now, I realize that it is not.  I don't know why I am doing this...  Thank you so much for the quick answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exercise is correct: for any non-negative integers $n$ and $k$ with $n\geq k$, we have
$$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
because, if I have $n+1$ balls and one of them is red,$\newcommand{\sft}[1]{\mathsf{\text{#1}}}$
$$\begin{align}
\binom{n+1}{k}=\begin{array}{c}
\sft{# of ways of choosing}\\
k\sft{ balls from }n+1\sft{ balls}
\end{array}&=\begin{array}{c}
\sft{# of ways of choosing}\\
k\sft{ balls from }n+1\sft{ balls}\\
\sft{in which the red ball}\\
\sft{IS chosen}
\end{array}\;\;+\;\;\begin{array}{c}
\sft{# of ways of choosing}\\
k\sft{ balls from }n+1\sft{ balls}\\
\sft{in which the red ball}\\
\sft{ISN'T chosen}
\end{array}\\[0.2in]
&=\begin{array}{c}
\sft{# of ways of choosing}\\
\sft{the other }k-1\sft{ balls}\\
\sft{from the }n\sft{ non-red balls}
\end{array}+\begin{array}{c}
\sft{# of ways of choosing}\\
\sft{all }k\sft{ balls}\\
\sft{from the }n\sft{ non-red balls}
\end{array}\\[0.2in]
&=\qquad\quad\binom{n}{k-1}\quad\quad+\qquad\qquad\binom{n}{k}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The other answer had a combinatorial proof of the identity, just in case you still need it, here I will present a computational proof of the same.
$$\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}=n!\left[\frac{1}{k(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)(n-k)!}\right]$$
$$=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\left[\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right]$$
$$=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\left[\frac{n+1}{k(n-k+1)}\right]$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)n!}{k(k-1)!\cdot (n-k+1)(n-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{k}$$
as required.