# Prove that $\binom{n+1}k = \binom nk + \binom n {k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

As the title says.

Prove that ${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$

It looks to me like induction but since there are two variables, I'm not really sure how to even set up a base case. If it is, in fact, induction.

Comment: This is [Pascal's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) and it has been asked before on here for sure.

Comment: Notice $k \leq n$, so induction via $n$ works.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but consider what the expansion of these terms looks like.  Can you see how to make the connection?

Comment: @GitGud Weren't able to find any. But well how to search for this anyways, too general terms...
@ Nick: I'll give it a shot since I weren't able to find a dupe.

Comment: You can do induction on n ($\ge 1$) by treating k ($ge 1$) as fixed.  But I think a direct proof is just as easy.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20475)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
So now
$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} & = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k-1)! (n-k+1)!} \\
& = \frac{n! (n-k+1)}{k! (n+1-k)!} + \frac{k n!}{k! (n+1-k)!} \\
& = \frac{(n+1-k+k)n!}{k! (n+1-k)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{k! (n+1-k)!} \\
& = \binom{n+1}{k}
\end{align*}$$
q.e.d.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first summand is if your choice of $k$ elements excludes the first element.

The second summand is if the $k$ elements includes the first element.

Comment: Nice. This answer stays much closer to the definition of the binomial coefficient than any induction proof can ever be.

Comment: @Peter What definition is that?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k} =$ the number of distinct subsets of cardinality $k$ of a set of $n$ elements.