# Mathematical induction with binomial coefficients

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove the following equation using mathematical induction: $$\sum \binom{n}{k}2^k = 3^n.$$ I am able to prove a similar induction without the $2^k$ on the left side and with $ 2^n $ on the right side, but I think this is probably a bit more complicated. Any ideas to start with? Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Without induction, just see $3^n=(2+1)^n$.

Comment: $2^k=2^k\times 1^{n-k}$ and $2+1=3$

Comment: thank you, this is what i did when a I tried to solve it with 2^n, it is quite easy, but the task is to use the MI, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this you'll need to use the following identity

$$
{n+1\choose k}={n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1} $$

The base case is $n=1$ and here the left hand side gives

$$
\sum_{k=0}^1 {1\choose k}2^k=1+2=3
$$

and so the base case is sorted. Now for the induction hypothesis we assume

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k=3^n
$$

Then using the identity at the start of the answer we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose k}2^k&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n\choose k}2^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n\choose k-1}2^k \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n\choose k-1}2^k \hspace{10pt}\text{since ${n\choose n+1}=0$} \\
&=3^n+\sum_{k=-1}^n {n\choose k} 2^{k+1} \\
&=3^n+2\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^k \hspace{10pt}\text{since ${n\choose -1}=0$} \\
&=3^n+2\cdot 3^n \\
&=(1+2)3^n \\
&=3^{n+1}
\end{align*}
and the induction step is complete. A proof of the identity at the start is not too hard and can be seen here [Prove that $\binom{n+1}k = \binom nk + \binom n {k-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502731/prove-that-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1)

Comment: Really nice. I appreciate your effort, it helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\binom{n+1}k2^k=\sum(\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k})2^k=2\sum\binom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1}+\sum\binom{n}{k}2^k$$$$=2.3^n+3^n=3^{n+1}$$

Here $\binom{n}{k}:=0$ if $k\notin\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $\sum$ must be read as $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}$

Under this definition:$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\binom{n}{k}2^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k$$

Comment: For the uninitiated, a comment on the summation indices would be nice.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is this edit okay? In my view it is the easiest way. No concerns about where it starts or ends.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, the upper index should be "n" and the lower should be "k = 0" (I didn´t know how to write it in MathJax. Thank you for your answer, I really like it.

Comment: It is nice that $\sum_{k=0}^n$ and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ come to the same under condition $\binom{n}{k}:=0$ if $k\notin\{0,\dots,n\}$ (as in my answer). You are welcome, cheers.

Comment: @Vera Yes, that is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Newton Binomial Formula $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$ with $a=1$ and $b=2$, we have, $3^n=(1+2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k$