# Evaluate the following combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Evaluate $C^{100}_{20} + 2*C^{99}_{20} + 3*C^{98}_{20}+...+81C^{20}_{20}$

Can someone give me hints. Is there an binomial theorem involved? I cant see it

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $$C_{20}^{100}+C_{20}^{99}+C_{20}^{98}+\cdots+C_{20}^{20}?$$

Comment: Yes leaving it in C form is fine. Nope i dont haha. Is there an identity? Possible just write for me an identity?

Comment: wow ok i found the identity.  $C^r_r + C^{r+1}_r + .. +C^n_r = C^{n+1}_{r+1}$

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939505/prove-that-sum-k-0nkmk-choose-m-nmn1-choose-m1-mn1-choose-m2/1939932#1939932

Comment: Sorry if its duplicate. Found the answer. Thanks @bof