# Proof by induction (Involving sets and factorials)

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

For all $k$, $n\in{\Bbb{N_0}}$ such that $k ≤ n$ we define:

$\binom{n}{k}:=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\in{\Bbb{Q}}$

I am trying to do a proof by induction for this question.

(a) Show that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$.

(b) Show that $\binom{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Any help is welcome as I am clueless!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thankyou! Thanks for retyping the question too! :)

Comment: For Pascal's identity see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20475).

Comment: For the second post see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11601).

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\binom{n-1}{k-1}+ \binom{n-1}{k}$

$=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{(k)!(n-k-1)!}$

$=\frac{k(n-1)!}{(k)!(n-k)!} + \frac{(n-k)(n-1)!}{(k)!(n-k)!}$

$=\frac{n(n-1)!}{(k)!(n-k)!}$

$=\frac{n!}{(k)!(n-k)!}$

$=\binom{n}{k}$

Now for the second part, first notice that $\binom{n}{1} = \frac{n!}{(1)!(n-1)!} = n$ is always an integer. This is going to be part of our base case.

We are going to use strong induction from now on.

Inductive step: assuming that $\binom{i}{j}$ is an positive integer for all $\binom{i}{j}$ that is both defined and satisfy $i \leq n$ and $j\leq n$, $j \leq i$.

now consider $\binom{n+1}{j}$. for j = n+1, this is 1 and we are done. if $j \le n+1$, then

$\binom{n+1}{j}$ = $\binom{n}{j-1}+ \binom{n}{j}$ by part (a). Then by inductive assumption, $\binom{n}{j-1}$ and $\binom{n}{j}$ are both integer so $\binom{n+1}{j}$ must be an integer

therefore $\binom{n+1}{j}$ is always an integer for all $j \leq n+1$

By induction, we can extend this too all $\binom{i}{j}$ that is defined. therefore, $\binom{n}{k}\in \mathbb{N} $ for all $0\leq k \leq n$