# Prove ${n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}$ using any particular number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I didn't really understand this proof to begin with, and I really don't understand what this question is asking. Do I just let n equal some number and then try to prove it from there, how do I begin the proof?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose

Comment: Have you ever work with the Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Didn't understand what proof? Did you try some method and get stuck? Or perhaps are confused about the notation?

Comment: What's your definition of $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: The question asks you to verify that the formula holds for particular values of $n$ and $k$.  For instance, if $n = 5$ and $k = 3$, you must show that $\binom{5}{3} = \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3}$.  You can prove *Pascal's formula* $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}$$ using an algebraic argument or a combinatorial argument such as that given below by Laars Helenius.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the left hand side counts the number of possible sets of size $k$ chosen from $n$ objects.

Now select one of the $n$ objects as special. Each set of size $k$ either contains our special object or it doesn't. There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ sets of size $k$ that include our special object and $\binom{n-1}{k}$ that do not.