# Proof of Pascal's rule by induction

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove pascal's rule by induction.Who could tell me how can I prove the following equation.
 i.e $$\dbinom{n}{k}=\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-1}{k}$$

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pascal's_Rule

Comment: unfortunately,all the answers mentioned above are  algebraic or combinatial proof ..I do need a proof by Induction..:-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm et al The OP specifically asked for an induction proof. None of the answers to the question you quote as a duplicate give an induction proof, so why did you close? Given that this is a fundamental result, which can be proved by induction, I do not see that the question is unreasonable.