# What's happening in this summation? $x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom {n+1}{k} x^{n-k+1}y^k + y^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}{k} x^{n+1-k}y^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Going through a lecture I encountered this fragment of one of induction proofs.

$$x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom {n+1}{k} x^{n-k+1}y^k + y^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}{k} x^{n+1-k}y^k$$

And as I'm not quite familiar yet with summation I'm really struggling to figure out why this is equal.
Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The terms $x^{n+1}$ and  $y^{n+1}$ correspond to the summands in the right-hand side obtained for $n=0$ and $n=k+1$. Notice these index are not taken in the first summation.

Comment: $\binom{n+1}0=\binom{n+1}{n+1}=1.$

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2195733)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&LHS-RHS\\&=x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}-\binom {n+1}{0}x^{n+1}y^0-\binom {n+1}{n+1}x^{0}y^{n+1}\\&=x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}\\&=0
\end{align}