# How to prove: $^nC_r + ^nC_{r+1} = ^{n+1}C_{r+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

**Prove: ${^n}C_r + ^nC_{r+1} = ^{n+1}C_{r+1}$**

I used $^nC_r = \frac{(n!)}{(n-r)!r!}$ and then did my substitutions:

$ = \frac{(n!)}{(n-r)!r!} + \frac{(n!)}{(n-(r+1))!(r+1)!}$

$ = \frac{(n!)}{(n-r)!r!} + \frac{(n!)}{(n-r-1)!(r+1)!}$

$=$

I am not sure how to do rest of the working out

Comment: Well, you have two fractions that you want to add together to a single fraction (since you want to compare it to $^{n+1}C_{r + 1}$). How would you usually do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving Pascal's Rule : ${{n} \choose {r}}={{n-1} \choose {r-1}}+{{n-1} \choose r}$ when $1\leq r\leq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose). Your $r$ and $n$ values are $1$ less than in the other question, and different notation is used, but otherwise they're the same, with this being called as commented in the other question, [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n!\cdot{(r+1)} +n!\cdot{(n-r)}}{(n-r)!\cdot{(r+1)!}}$$
$$=\frac{n!\cdot{(n+1)}}{((n+1)-(r+1))!\cdot{(r+1)!}} $$
$$=^{n+1}C_{r+1}$$

Comment: how did you get $${(n-r)!\cdot{(r+1)!}}$$

Comment: See the denominator

Comment: In the denominator we take the LCM

Answer (score 0):

A combinatorical way:
Choose $r+1$ elements from a set of $n+1$ different element.
This can be done in $\dbinom{n+1}{r+1}$ or we can count the ways to choose $r+1$ elements from the same set without the element $X$ and the ways to choose $r+1$ elements from the set where $X$ is part of these $r+1$ numbers, this can be done in $\dbinom{n}{r+1}+\dbinom{n}{r}$ .
And since we are counting the same thing we are done.

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{align}
\binom n{k+1}+\binom n{k}&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}\left[1+\frac{k+1}{n-k}\right]\\
&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n-k}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: how does that equal to (n+1     K+1)

Comment: Just replace $k$ with $k+1$ in both sides of equality.

Comment: can you please show those changes on your solution

Comment: @DevPatel Done.

Comment: what happens to the (n-k)!

Comment: @DevPatel Which one?

Comment: the answer u have given is (n+1 K+1) but before that step what happened to (n-k)! in $\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$

Comment: $n-k=(n+1)-(k+1).$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90398/discussion-between-dev-patel-and-user).

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to express his/her motivation.